# I want to access containers from host using IP address like in VM in Windows 10/11 - is it any containers allowing it?

Tags: windows, docker, cassandra, windows-10, containers

I want do expose Cassandra database cluster on 4 IP addresses with same ports (different ports is not possible since software limitation - so please not recommend me to use port forwarding - it is not usable).

Is it any container system smarter than Docker Destop/WSL which no allow access host->container by IP address? Docker allow only container->host via IP.

I am doing it without problem with VM machines. I have no idea why containers cannot have multiple IP addresses visible to host - why it is not possible since internally they have IP addresses?

How to do such routing from containers network to host and host to containers?

I have weak experience with other containers than Docker.

Comment: As I indicated on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73145965), Docker Desktop doesn't allow you to access the per-container IP addresses.  If you have a working VM setup, sticking with that seems like a practical answer.

Comment: Question is "Is it any container system smarter than Docker Destop/WSL" - so why do you explain that Docker do not allow this since you explained it before? Do you do not read question before you sent comment?